# Recursively Fetch Data from Table

Tags: sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I have a master table like this -

```
Table(Feature, PrjctNo, Instance)
```

Each record here is unique. Say,

```
FTR1, PrjctA, Instance1
FTR1, PrjctB, Instance2
FTR2, PrjctA, Instance2
FTR2, PrjctB, Instance1
FTR3, PrjctA, Instance5
FTR4, PrjctA, Instance0
```

Basically, each feature can be mapped to multiple projects. And each project can be mapped to multiple feature but the instance of that project for each feature will be unique.

What I have is a table with a subset of FTR No's from the master table. Now, I want to retrieve all the projects from the master associated with these features.

Now, since each of these projects can be associated to multiple other features, I need to identify those records such that the Instance of the projects is always higher than the already existing one.

Ex : Given that I have a subset (FTR1, FTR2)

Iteration 1 :

```
FTR1, PrjctA, Instance1
FTR1, PrjctB, Instance2
FTR2, PrjctA, Instance2
FTR2, PrjctB, Instance1
```

Iteration 2: Check if there any other features associated to any of the projects fetched above. So, after iteration 2, the result set should look like :

```
FTR1, PrjctA, Instance1
FTR1, PrjctB, Instance2
FTR2, PrjctA, Instance2
FTR2, PrjctB, Instance1
FTR3, PrjctA, Instance5
```

We won't add the record with Instance0 of PrjctA. We always have to fetch the higher instance.

How can I accomplish this using SQL server?

Comment: Do you have fixed number of iterations? Is it always two iterations?

Comment: No, this has to continue recursively as long as I am able to find new features and tables.

Comment: It would help if you extended your sample data and sample result with few more rows and few more iterations. Right now the logic is not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the CTE below will work assuming all your "Instance" columns are formatted exactly as "Instance" and then a number. Your logic requires a natural sort of the instance column.

If your column format is consistent, then this is as trivial as removing the "Instance" prefix and then sorting numerically to enforce the business rule around subsequent instances.

If the format is not consistent, then you'll need a more elaborate way to compare the instances. You could either use REPLICATE and STUFF to stuff the necessary '0' values when comparing instances of different lengths or a CTE to utilize a regex match and to perform more efficiently.

Here's the CTE:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        Feature,
        PrjctNo,
        Instance
    FROM @Features
    WHERE Feature IN ('FTR1', 'FTR2')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        F.Feature,
        F.PrjctNo,
        F.Instance
    FROM CTE
        INNER JOIN @Features F
            ON CTE.PrjctNo = F.PrjctNo
                AND CTE.Feature <> F.Feature
    WHERE CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(CTE.Instance, 'Instance', ''))
        < CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(F.Instance, 'Instance', ''))
)
    SELECT
        Feature
    FROM CTE
    GROUP BY
        Feature
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

This works off the sample data below:

```
DECLARE @Features TABLE (
    Feature VARCHAR(10),
    PrjctNo VARCHAR(15),
    Instance VARCHAR(15)
)
INSERT @Features VALUES
    ('FTR1', 'PrjctA', 'Instance1'),
    ('FTR1', 'PrjctB', 'Instance2'),
    ('FTR2', 'PrjctA', 'Instance2'),
    ('FTR2', 'PrjctB', 'Instance1'),
    ('FTR3', 'PrjctA', 'Instance5'),
    ('FTR4', 'PrjctA', 'Instance0')
```

The above example outputs your desired result:

```
Feature
----------
FTR1
FTR2
FTR3
```